# Sharepoint 2010 credentials always prompting

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, login

When i click on any link in the SharePoint environment a log-in prompt keeps coming up, and i have to click the Cancel button in-order to access any link i clicked.

Can i get any advice as to what may have caused this and how to fix such issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE!!!!
When i logged in as system account(Farm admin) it didn't prompt for credentials on the client workstation, however when i use any other account it prompts me again and have to click Cancel to continue.

Comment: This symptom could be alot of things really, the first question is are we talking about accessing the site directly on the server or from a client workstation, next one will be is the site in the Local Intranet zone for IE.

Comment: Accessing the site from a client workstation and yes it is also in a local intranet zone for IE.

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer or Firefox?  Firefox is a different fix.

Comment: I use IE mainly for SharePoint, and the local intranet zone didn't work. The prompt came up for the client workstation, but doesn't prompt when i am on the server. anymore suggestion.

Comment: Hi @wayne9999, did you get an answer to this? It suddenly started to happen on my laptop and it appears to only affect me (not other users). I happens on both my IE8 and Chrome, and it is annoying me. grrrrrr.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the time services on client and server are both synchronized on the same source and/or got the exact same value.

Authentication issues like this often raise when time is not sync.

Comment: I will look into that aspect of the timer service and see how best your suggestion can work.

Comment: the time service is OK, no problem because both server and client machine sync.

Answer (score 1):

To enable IE to store your login credentials: 
http://www.sharepointboris.net/2006/10/logging-to-sharepoint-through-internet-and-password-problems/

If you're using Windows 7 or Vista, you might want to make some additional steps so opening explorer view or office documents wouldn't prompt you for credentials:

http://www.sharepointboris.net/2010/03/windows-7vista-trouble-with-sharepoints-explorer-view-and-office-documents-freezing-or-prompting-for-user-credentials/

Comment: the above mentioned sites didnt resolved the issue either, i really do appreciate everyone trying to help me out, is there any other suggestion that you can come up with for me to try out.